# How to extend interface property of react-select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I want to remove any from the options, How should I do it? Also options could be array of any objects structure.

```
import Select from "react-select";

export interface Props {
  label?: string;
  id: string;
  options: any;
}

export const Filter = ({ label, id,options, ...props }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {label && (
        <label>
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
      <Select id={id} options={options} />
    </>
  );
};

Filter.defaultProps = {
  label: "",
  id: "",
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example might help you. It shows how to use a customized interface for your options.

[Multi-select text input](https://codesandbox.io/s/u7ztnl?module=/example.tsx&file=/example.tsx)